# SQLi with error messages but no output

Tags: sql-injection

With the authorization of the owner, I was testing a website and when I put in some sql query and has some syntax error, it shows me, but when I test it with a parameter like

`p.php?id=66+/*!60000select*/+*+/*!60000from*/+data`

the output does not appear, but I know that `data` is a valid parameter because if I put in something else, I get the `Unknown column 'name_here' in 'where clause'`.

In this case, we can consider this as a blind SQLi?

Comment: Hard to say without more info. Try exploiting it with SQLMap.

Comment: Blind SQLi means that the sql statement was processed but no output is displayed. Do you have anything to suggest that the server is processing the query? The lack of output is only the "blind" part of SQLi. You still need the SQLi part ...

Answer (score 2):

A blind SQL is possible and may be confirmed by injecting WAITFOR DELAY or sleep in the query, depending on the target DBMS. **SQLMap** would be the right tool to test that.

Also, you should look at the HTTP status code and HTML **source code**. It's possible that you are seeing a blank page in your browser because the markup is broken, but there is still output even though you are not seeing it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if the encoding/waf bypass is required for exploitation, but the page appears to be vulnerable to error based injection. Most blind injection based techniques tend to use time based payloads which are both error prone and slow. Since the page is showing SQL errors you should be able to extract the data this way. Try the following payload (might need the /* comments, etc added back in if a waf is in use)"

```
p.php?id=(SELECT * FROM (SELECT NAME_CONST(version(),1),NAME_CONST(version(),1)) as x)--
```

It should respond with an error like this, with `8.0.27` being the version of the database server:

```
ERROR 1060 (42S21) at line 16: Duplicate column name '8.0.27'
```